# Cucumberjs and Gherkin: Why can not I use "And" and "But" steps?

Tags: gherkin, cucumberjs

When I try to use the steps "And" or "But" in Cucumberjs I get a reference error. Those objects are not found. However for the Steps "Given", "When" and "Then I have no problem and I can work normally. Why does this happen?

Example of Gherkin feature where it is possible to look at the use of the step **And**:

[image]

In [the Cucumberjs's documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md) only mention the three Steps that I am using.

What should I do to be able to use these Steps?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`And` and `But` don't exist for defining steps
(in the current version, v4.2.1 - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/src/index.js)

And I'm pretty sure thats **by design**:

Since `And` and `But` are only syntactic sugar that depend on context of previous steps, so I'd recommend defining your *step definitions* with `Given`, `When` and `Then`.

From you example:

`And('the credit card is valid', () => {...})`

Without usage context would not tell you whether the step is doing a *validation* or an *action*. So, define the step instead as:

`Given('the credit card is valid', () => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

> To Cucumber steps beginning with And or But are exactly the same kind of steps as all the others.

Please see cucumber [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then).

Comment: I know that. There is no difference between any of them, but they help us to give semantics to the user story.

Comment: You can still use them in feature files but the generated step definition will be either Then or When.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although in Cucumber it is not possible to use these Steps, it is very helpful to use it in Gherkin.